# Validate the TextBoxes in the GridView based on a value in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a GridView whose columns names are ID, Name, Price, Tolerance, Remarks and Value_f.
I have TextBoxes in the Template Field for Price, Tolerance and Remarks. I have one Button called "Save Button" below the Gridview.
I bind the values for ID, Name and Value_f from the Backend datatable.

Now the problem is,
I have to validate the textboxes in the Gridview when I press the Save Button. Suppose if the Value_f field from the DataTable has value `'1'`, then I should not validate the TextBoxes in the GridView. How to Validate based on these conditions?

For the normal validation, I placed RequiredFieldValidator for the TextBoxes and Sets the TextBox property `ValidationGroup = "Grid"` and I assign the same to the "Save Button". But in this case, I dont know how to validate the controls in the Client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom JS function and call JS function on `Button OnClientClick event`.

For example:

```
function textboxFinder(obj)
{
        var grd = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_' + obj);
        var inputs = grd.getElementsByTagName('input')
        var txtId = 'txtQuantity' //ID of textbox in GridView Template

        for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
        {
            if(inputs[i].type == 'text')
            {
                if(inputs[i].id.indexOf(txtId) != -1) 
                {
                    //HERE YOUR CUSTOM CODE COMES HERE
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Calling Function

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClientClick="textboxFinder('GRID VIEW ID');"/>
```

Comment: How do I check the Value_f value here? I am a zero in JavaScript.